# Equal to or equal to syntax

Tags: ruby

In ruby I can write

```
a == b || a == c
```

It will return true if `b` or `c` is equal to `a`.

But this syntax is not very pretty when I want to check many variables against `a`

```
a == b || a == c || a == d || a == e || a == f
```

**Is there a beautiful way to do this?**

Something like this

```
a ==|| [b,c,d,e,f]
```

for the `OR` and

```
a ==&& [b,c,d,e,f]
```

for the `AND` would be great.

Comment: Andreas, I changed my answer.

Comment: Yeah. It is a good answer and I've voted it up, but I think the include? solution is the best.

Comment: That's fine, Andreas.  I just wanted you to know about using `case` for your requirement.  I often chose to use `case` over `if/then/else` because I find it more expressive and more compact.  Also, because `case` uses `===`, rather than `==` for evaluating boolean expressions, it is handy when you want to branch on an object's class.  For example, instead of `if o.is_a? String...elif o.is_a? Array...`, you can write `case a; when String...when Array...`.  My apologies if this is old news.

Comment: No apologies needed. Thanks for your commitment! I use `case` whenever I can. The whole point of this question was to find compact and better ways to express our syntax. For later viewers all answers to this question have great value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
[b,c,d,e,f].include? a
```

The `AND` flavor means that all variables should be equal to each other, so I guess this would work:

```
[a,b,c,d,e,f].uniq.size == 1
```

Comment: The last one is not relevant. Author never asked for comparison between B and F. He wanted only `include?` (although he might benefit from the `uniq` trick in the future :) ).

Comment: The OP asked for `a ==&& [b,c,d,e,f]` which means that `a == b && a == c && ...` implicitly this also means `b == c` and `b == f`...

Comment: Point! I've missed the last line of the question

Answer (score 6):

Yes using [`#any?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) for `or` :

```
 [b,c,d,e,f].any? { |e| e == a }
```

For `and`, use [`all?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F)

```
 [b,c,d,e,f].all? { |e| e == a }
```

Comment: This is a great answer but, the `include?` method  is the least complex one. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @AndreasLyngstad I might think of that, if you even mention, what actually object types are `c`, `b` etc.. I thought as per your example, those are custom objects, and you have `#==` method to compare those, and you are looking for *one liner*. If you mention your objects as `'b'`,`'c'` etc or `1,2,4,..` then I would suggest you something, what I didn't here. Anyway if your problem is gone now, enjoy your code..

Comment: I had this ugly line `if @car.status == 8 or @car.status == 9 or @car.status == 10`, so `if [8,9, 10].include? @car.status` looks best in this case. Wish I could accept more than one answer. Will use your technique in other places.

Comment: @AndreasLyngstad  Its ok.. Ruby is fun... :-)

Answer (score 3):

My preference would be to use a `case` statement, because I think it reads best:

```
case a
when b,c,d,e,f
  ..do something..
else
  ..do something else..
end
```

You could also use set-like operations.

```
arr = [b,c,d,e,f]
```

To determine if `a` equals any of the elements of `arr`:

```
(arr & [a]).any?
```

To determine if all of the elements of `arr` equal `a`:

```
(arr - [a]).empty?
```

Lastly (since using `uniq`--the obvious solution--has already been suggested), a fun way of checking if they are all the same, when they are comparable (i.e, `<=>` defined):

```
arr = [a,b,c,d,e,f]
arr.min == arr.max
```

Comment: IIRC, slower than the other suggested solution, but still brief and readable!

Comment: That's an old acronym, If I Recall/Remember Correctly

Comment: @quetzalcoatl, thanks.  (Other readers: quetzalcoatl's first comment referred to the set-like solution, as I later edited to add the `case` statement.)  I'm not aware of the relative efficiency of any of the methods suggested, except to observe that they must all enumerate a list.